# Adjusting time scale in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot date-time relationship but I have some problems with ticks and labels for time-axis. First, I want labels to be in `"%H:%M"` format instead of `"%H:%M:%S"`. Also, I want ticks to be every 10 minutes instead of every hour. I tried a bunch of methods, but the only one that worked was transforming data from `<time>` to `<chr>`. Unfortunately, I also need `geom_smooth` function for my plot, which doesn't work with characters.

Here's my code with partial dataset.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  date=c("08-01","08-02","08-03","08-04","08-05",
         "08-06","08-07","08-08","08-09","08-10",
         "08-11","08-12","08-13","08-14","08-15"),

  a=c("10:10","09:40","09:40","09:40","09:40",
          "09:40","09:40","09:40","09:50","09:40",
          "08:00","09:40","09:40","09:40","09:40"),

  s=c("11:30","11:40","11:30","11:10","",
          "11:30","11:50","11:50","11:30","11:50",
          "","","11:30","12:20","11:20"))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(date = parse_date(str_c("2019", date, sep = "-")),
         a = parse_time(a),
         s = parse_time(s) )

ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = date, y = a), color='darkgreen') +
  geom_point(aes(x = date, y = s), color = 'darkblue') + 
  geom_smooth(aes(x = date, y = s), color = 'darkblue') + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day", date_labels = "%m.%d") +
  labs(x = "date", y = "time") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 1))
```

And here's my plot:

[image: And here's my plot]

Comment: I think `scale_y_time()` will do what you need.

Comment: I tried, but I wasn't able to figure out a way to set `labels` and `breaks` arguements.

Comment: Use `date_breaks="10 min"` and `date_labels="%H:%M"`

Comment: @Dave2e date_breaks="10 min" is not an accepted argument in the scale_y_time() geom. The usage is date_breaks = waiver(). How would you format it so it runs?

Comment: @SusieDerkins, time is a standardized object and ggplot does not seem to handle it in a standard way.  I would follow the solution in accepted answer and convert to a POSIXct object and use the above notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest working with POSIXct time formats for use with ggplot - sometimes 'hms' objects do not parse correctly with time axes.  Try modifying your code as follows: (also incorporating Dave2e's comment)

```
df <- tibble(...   )

df <- df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(paste("2019",date,sep="-"), format="%Y-%m-%d"),
         a = as.POSIXct(a, format="%H:%M"),
         s = as.POSIXct(s, format="%H:%M"))

ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = date, y = a), color='darkgreen') +
  geom_point(aes(x = date, y = s), color = 'darkblue') + 
  geom_smooth(aes(x = date, y = s), color = 'darkblue') + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day", date_labels = "%m.%d") +
  scale_y_datetime(date_breaks = "10 min", date_labels = "%H:%M") +
  labs(x = "date", y = "time") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 1))
```